# Checkbox not being displayed under a ListView in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, dialog

I would like to have an AlertDialog that displays a Listview on top, and a checkbox on the bottom. Here is the code I use:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                    final ListView lv = new ListView(mContext);               
                    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(mContext);
                    checkbox.setText("Make this default");
                    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ReaderOptions));                                       
                     lv.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));           
                    lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                     layout.addView(lv);
                     layout.addView(checkbox);
```

The problem is that the checkbox doesnt get displayed, only a blank space.  Whats the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a LinearLayout make sure that the orientation is set the way you want. The default orientation for LinearLayout is horizontal, so I suspect that your CheckBox is to the right of your ListView, outside the screen, where you cannot see it. Try explicitly setting the orientation to vertical. But do it in XML as CommonsWare suggests

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the height of a `ListView`. Use a height of `0` and a weight of `1`.

And, consider doing this in an XML layout resource and inflating it, rather than assembling it from Java code.